# AD incremental search timeout

Tags: ldap

I have a product which runs full sync per day and incr sync per 30 mins. It has a search filter like: ‘(|(&(objectClass=User)(!(ObjectClass=Computer))((memberOf={some_dn}))))’.  The cookie generated by full sync or incr sync will be used as the input of next incr search.
On our env, after 15 times successful incr sync (for other cases, maybe only 4 times), the 16th incr sync stuck (Wait AD server response since the timeout for DirectorySearch is set to -1. Yes I can set expire like 5 mins but it still doesn't return what you want). When I picked up the cookie for this failed incr search and ran it in my another standalone app (Just a WinForm filled with DirectorySearch code), it also stuck.

Another strange thing is when I checked log and got those cookies used by previous 15 successful incr search and ran in my standalone app, all of these 15 cookies stuck!
One more strange thing happened when I still used the cookie for the 16th incr search, but changed the filter to '(&(objectClass=User)(!(ObjectClass=Computer)))’     (here I removed member={...}), the search can pass.

The only thing we can recover our product is to have another full sync which always works, then incr search after this full sync can pass. But the incr search will stuck again after N times of incr sync.

The code should look like below:

```
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher()
{
    ClientTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1),
    ServerPageTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1),
    ServerTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1),
    DerefAlias = DereferenceAlias.Never,
    ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.None
};
searcher.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(basePath);
searcher.Filter = extraFilter;
searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
searcher.CacheResults = false;
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(new string[] { "name", "mail" });
searcher.DirectorySynchronization = new DirectorySynchronization();
searcher.DirectorySynchronization.Option |= DirectorySynchronizationOptions.ObjectSecurity
                                            | DirectorySynchronizationOptions.ParentsFirst;
searcher.DirectorySynchronization.Option |= DirectorySynchronizationOptions.IncrementalValues;
searcher.DirectorySynchronization.ResetDirectorySynchronizationCookie(Convert.FromBase64String(cookie));
searcher.ExtendedDN = ExtendedDN.HexString;
```

Is there some wrong in my code or it is a bug In MS AD? My AD is MS AD 2012.

updated 09/09/2018:
Eventually, it's a bug of AD 2008,2012 and Microsoft will release a patch soon.

Comment: There is only 10+ users in my AD. so performance should be ok.

Comment: Show us some code you are using.

Comment: Eventually, it's a bug on AD 2008~12 and Microsoft will release a patch soon.